# Initializing a class that consist of many classes in such a way that one of the classes has different attributes

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x

Here are the classes and their relations:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AdA7.png

Code for clarification:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = 1

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = A()

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = A()


class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr1 = B()
        self.atr2 = C()


test1 = D()
```

Now what do I do if I want to initialize `D` in such a way that `A`'s `self.atr = 2`, and that change reflects to all those classes (`B` and `C`) that use `A` as well when I initialize `D`

Like I imagine it in pseudo code:

```
test2 = D(A.self.atr = 2)
```

So you initialize `D` in such a manner that `A`'s `self.atr = 2`

Comment: You don't. In good OO design, `D` neither knows or cares that `B` and `C` use `A` in their implementation. If `B` or `C` need their instance of `A` to be modified, they will provide a way to do so in their own `__init__`. For that matter, `A` itself does not provide a way to specify a value for `atr` when you create an instance.

Comment: Going with what chepner said, the only things similar would probably be a base class. Where B and C inherit off of base class A. Then it would just be a property they all have.

Comment: @chepner But by disallowing this, don't you lose a huge amount of utility? Like in my example, if A were a card, B a deck, C a player, and D a game, then you could easily generate 10 games in such a way, that each card has unique properties aside from the other 9 generated games, because when you generate D (the game), you can easily make each card of the game to have unique qualities, by changing the card's class (A). How I could do this?

Comment: At a minimum, you start by letting `A.__init__` take a value to assign to `atr`, so that `B` and `C` can each pass a value when instantiating `A`. Then, you do the same for `B` and `C`, so that `D` can pass a value when it instantiates `B` and `C`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I have tried that model, but it is very bothersome to write, and kind of ugly, so much manual work, and you have to edit every existing class to suit that model. If you know any other way, even if it would not be according to best practices, I would like to know, I'm not going to implement anything serious yet, I'm just studying and experimenting on Python.

Comment: The way the classes are currently defined, there's nothing you can do. You could modify `A` only to set `atr` based on the value of a global variable which you set before instantiating `D` (terrible idea), or you could manually set `D.atr1.atr.atr` and `D.atr2.atr.atr` after instantiating `D` (cumbersome). But the fact is, you're looking for an alternative to good design. If `A` is meant to be configurable, then make it so.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your comments, they have been helpful, however, if the class I want to configure is used in 100 other classes, I have to write stupid amount of code, and track down every use case of that class, to make each instance of that class in the program to be configured properly, that is just absurd, there has to be a better way.

Comment: Why are you assuming there is a magic solution to bad design?

Comment: @chepner Because replacing one part of a program with another part, or running a program with a modified parts can be very useful, I can't believe there is no automated way to replace all certain parts of the program with other parts, so you could run, for example, 100 different variations of that program, each time, testing what part would be the best fit. Like if you program a house, why would you not want to be able to change all nails used in a house to be changed to bolts, or something else, so you could test what is for the best? Isn't that only natural?

Comment: There are valid reasons for using a design like you have above. For instance, you could rewrite `B` to use something entirely different instead of `A`, and such a change would not affect `D` (read up on encapsulation). But if you want flexibility, you *have* to design for it; you don't just get it for free.

Comment: @chepner Well what would be a good method to design for it, all aforementioned ideas seemed kinda bad.

Comment: You're going to have to come up with a more concrete example if you want a better suggestion. As it is, I can only reiterate my previous comments and jsbueno's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want B and C to have different properties, as required by a call from D, the way to do that is to pass parameters for the initialization of B and C so that they know what to do.

The parameter can be itself an instance of A, where the attributes you care for are set before inistantiatin B and C:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, atr=1):
        self.atr = atr

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.atr = config

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.atr = config

class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        my_a = A(2)
        self.atr1 = B(my_a)
        self.atr2 = C(my_a)

test1 = D()
```

**update**
I see from the comments above you seem to dislike this approach duew to the impression you'd have a lot of repetitive code everywhere - 
That is not the case however - if for example, you have a lot of classes that have to be "preconfigured" like class A, passed to a lot of other classes, you could just create a bundle of all classes pre-configured - you'd still pass on a single parameter to each instance you create.

Also, there are, as you want, mechanisms in Python to allow dynamically reconfiguring classes  - using "variables" being one of them - the probelm is that doing it in this naive way you want, you'd ahve pretty soon an unmaintainable mess.

For example, if you just use a module-level (= global) variable for "1" instead of hardcoding it into A, you could do:

```
CURRENT_ATR_VALUE = 1
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = CURRENT_ATR_VALUE

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = A()

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = A()


class D(object):
    def __init__(self, atr):
        global CURRENT_ATR_VALUE
        old = CURRENT_ATR_VALUE 
        CURRENT_ATR_VALUE = atr
        self.atr1 = B()
        self.atr2 = C()
        CURRENT_ATR_VALUE = old


test1 = D(atr=2)
```

This would have thge exact effect you are intending, could not be simpler - whithout requiring any of the Language's advanced introspection capabilities, and still would lead you soon to an unmaintainable mess. The way passing parameters around does contain the custom values in the scopes they are wanted, without side-effects, not even in a multi-threading or multi-processing running environment, and is far more recomendable.

If you really want to mess things around, you could create a factory function that would produce a *new* class "A" with the desired attributes, and inject it in the module global namespace as a new "A" class while you instantiate the others - that would be "fancier" and maybe is what you'd like. Just write A inside something like:

```
def A_factory(atr=1):    
    class A(object):
        def __init__(self, atr=1):
            self.atr = atr
    globals()["A"] = A

# creates default "A" class
A_factory(1)
```

And call this factory with your desired "atr" while instantiating "B" and "C" as above. This is absolutely unmanageable, but it is ultimately what you are asking for. T

Comment: There is a slight difference here. In the original, the instances of `B` and `C` each had their own instance of `A` as an attribute. Here, they are sharing a single instance. Whether that matters depends on the actual classes involved.

Comment: Indeed  - anyway if that is desired intent, the solution under this model is to create one instance for each call where an instance of A is passed.